# Telerik Sitefinity Add Property User

Tags: sitefinity

In my Sitefinity back-end there is a user section that I would like to add some setting. Something like DisplayLink where it would be a boolean value that I can set on Login of the user. Is there a way I can do that? I am using sf 14 and can't find anyway to add some setting for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this is what you need](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/how-to-add-delete-a-field-showing-on-admin-panel-users-list) ...map the view externally and modify.

However keep in mind these views pull in the XHR JSON and you just expose it to the grid... Open your console and view the XHR network traffic to see the JSON object per user.  There's a "Comment" field you might be able to leverage, but man the best way would be to just use a ROLE... because they can be filtered, and already come across in that JSON.

Another thing to note, is this is an **OLD UI** screen and likely will get revamped in the next few releases of Sitefinity rendering everything you're doing pointless... (have to re-do it with likely the new AdminApp Extensions)